# iOS: Pin an image & url into the Pinterest App via URL Scheme

Tags: ios, pinterest

I have an imageURL, and a weblinkURL that is to be shared. I want to open the Pinterest app automatically via url scheme, and pass these parameters so that this is possible.

Is there any legit url schemes out there?

Yes, I did check their dev page: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/, they have an SDK, but I want a simple url scheme. I don't want to do the integration.

(It looks like few other apps can do this now - what is the right way to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

Pin 
`pinterest://pin/285063851385287883/`

Board
`pinterest://board/meaghanror/cats-cats-cats/`

User
`pinterest://user/carlrice/`

Source: [Custom URL scheme for Pinterest on iOS Safari to open board URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624328/custom-url-scheme-for-pinterest-on-ios-safari-to-open-board-url)